# how is clipping done in regions by circles and rectangles, square?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

[image]

How to shade the region like this?

Comment: Well you could start by showing us how to draw the path? (people tend to not like questions like "do this for me", at least show some effort). I tried making it with the patterns library, but wasn't satisfied with the results.

Comment: I was mistaken, you can just draw the curve as a closed curve (`-- cycle`) at the end and use the patterns lib. Note that not al PDF viewers are 100% accurate in showing the clipped patterned area. My version of Evince doesn't show this correctly on screen, but prints it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't need to clip

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=vertical lines] (3,0) arc (0:90:3) arc (180:270:2) |- (3,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]